# Guide to implement Seamless sign-in and sign-up flows

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-developers-console, seamless-login

I want to implement Google's One tap sign-up and automatic sign-in in my website with the help of documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/ but I am getting confused on how to place the codes

Thanks

Comment: You should evaluate more you question, as it looks too broad for now. Best would be preparing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

The beta test program for that API is closed. Google said that's improving the API's cross-browser functionality and will provide updates in the coming months. 
Only Tripadvisor and other few companies (IMHO that's not fair) can benefit of the seamless autologin (and upgrades)